# Decrease Qt GUI application size

Tags: c++, qt, dll, static-libraries

I'm learning to develop apps using Qt Creator. I have built a simple app under Windows, depends on uses mingwm10.dll, QtCore4.dll, QtGui4.dll, QtNetwork4.dll.
Out of QtQui4.dll I use only a a couple of widgets, and don't need all of the rest... Is it possible to either shrink the size of QtGui4.dll or do something else to decrease deployment size of application?
How about static linking? Will it embed the whole dll, or only parts of it that are used?
And also is it possible with Qt to link some dlls staticly and some dynamicly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not possible to shrink the QtGui4.dll by removing some functions. Trolltech is [having a look at this](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/04/17/size-matters/), but the good solution seems quite distant:

Static linking, I think it is very problematic on windows. Each time I tried, it was a nightmare.

So, it looks like you are stuck with the regular DLL. The only thing you can do (which I do for my Qt apps is):

- use [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) to compress your DLL

or

- use strong compression in your installer

If you already UPX your dll, you can not reduce it further with the installer compression, but this can reduce other files.

Comment: Yea, "UPX -9 QtGui4.dll" is the way to go :)

Comment: Interesting tip, I've never used UPX before.

Comment: Thank you! What is the smallest footprint of GUI Qt app you could archive this way?

Comment: I think it is possible to remove some unwanted functions. See [Hatchet](https://www.rfk.id.au/blog/entry/hatchet-hack-frozen-pyside-apps/)

Answer (score 7):

The best way is to manually configure the Qt library with configure. By issuing

```
configure --help
```

you'll see a number of options that might help reduce both disk and memory footprint. E.g.

```
--no-stl
--no-exceptions
```

can both reduce the footprint of your application. You can also modify the mkspec to use more aggressive optimization flags for your compiler.

Answer (score 2):

If you link statically you end up with a 1.5GB exe and you sacrifice some functionality like plug-ins. So it's not really worth it unless you don't want to distribute the dlls. But yeah, you could try Henrik's suggestion and also exclude Webkit which is probably the biggest chunk of code.

Comment: In the context of the original question, excluding WebKit does not make any difference as he did not use it (only Core, Gui, Network modules).